# How to add buttons to each row in a dataTable?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, datatable

I've added a table to my which dynamically creates the table columns and rows.
What I'm trying to do now is add an *Edit* and *Delete* button to each row in that table.

In order to achieve that I tried placing two td's containing the buttons wihthin the for..each loop that creates the table rows.:

```
@foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray) {
  <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:11px">@cell.ToString()</td>
  <td><a class="btn-success">Edit</a></td>
  <td><a class="btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
}
```

But this add two buttons to each cell in every row which is not the intended outcome.

**Question:**

How can buttons be dynamically created for each row in a data table?

**Razr markup for table:**

```
 <table id="escalation" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
            {
                <th style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #7591ac; ">@col.Caption</th>

            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:11px">@cell.ToString()</td>
                    <td><a class="btn-success">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a class="btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
                }

            </tr>
        } 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This blog has some good info on this and there is a nuget package for begin  collection item http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should put the buttons to the first foreach because this is which runs through the rows. You should use this code. It will generate the two button to the end of the row.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
            {
                <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:11px">@cell.ToString()</td>
            }

            <td><a class="btn-success">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a class="btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    } 
</tbody>
```